# Как подключиться к базе данных используя rdp файл?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, rdp, dbeaver

Мне нужно подключиться к MS SQL Server чтобы делать запросы (в идеальном варианте через Power BI, но можно и  Dbeaver). На запрос доступа админы скинули мне файл .rdp - сами они говорят что с базами данных не работали и не знают как к ним подключаться. Вопрос - это вообще возможно сделать через этот файл?

Comment: Это файл для удалённого подключения к рабочему столу. Видимо, сервера. Просто запускай его как ярлык. Если там установлен MS SQL, то верным делом в меню найдутся и штатные инструменты для работы с ним. Настрой себе доступ (адрес у сервера, надеюсь, статический) и общайся.

Answer (score 1):

С вашими вводными, устанавливать нужные приложения на удаленном сервере, и управлять этими приложениями по Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP)

Answer (score 0):

Вы открываете файл, что вам прислали админы (с разрешением rdp). Это доступ к удаленному компьютеру. Если все пройдет штатно, то у вас откроется на вашем рабочем столе рабочий стол удаленного компьютера и вы сможете с ним работать. Уже там, на удаленном компьютере надо будет ставить Dbeaver  или PowerBI, может уже даже это все установлено там. И через эти вот программы вы сможете работать со своей базой данной.